# How can i seperate number and string (Beginner,JS)

Tags: javascript

**

1. **I wonder why else code isnt working I tried convert to number but

   still doesnt working.**

**
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EkM2.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8rv3.jpg)

```
    function KareAlan() {
 var kare1 = document.getElementById("kare1")
  .value;
 var kare1n = parseInt(kare1, 10)

 if (typeof kare1n == "number") {
  kare1 = kare1 * kare1 * kare1;
  document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML =
   "Result:" + " " + kare1;
 } else if (typeof kare1n == "string") {

  document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML =
   "This procces is not possible,you should input at least one number";
 }

}
```

Comment: The `else` part is working, but `typeof NaN` is `number`, you've to use `isNaN` check.

Comment: `NaN` is of type `"number"` (yeah I know...) so instead of checking the type, check `if (!isNaN(kare1n))` and replace the `else if()` with a simple `else`

Answer (score 0):

Use !isNaN(number) to check for numbers.

We use isNaN() which returns true if it isn't a number and then we negate the statement to get a function which returns true if it s a number.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out the value `NaN` is a `number`. You need to check for `typeof` before you `parse` run the code to see what happens

```js
var theApple  = "Apple";
var theNumber = 1234;
console.log(
  "log line 1: " + theApple,
  parseInt(theApple, 10),
  "| typeof: " + typeof(theApple),
  "| typeof parsedInt: " + typeof(parseInt(theApple, 10)),

);

console.log(
  "log line 2: " + theNumber,
  parseInt(theNumber, 10),
  "| typeof: " + typeof(theNumber),
  "| typeof parsedInt: " + typeof(parseInt(theNumber, 10)),

);

// or simply

console.log("log line 3: ", !isNaN(theApple));
console.log("log line 4: ", !isNaN(theNumber));

// the problem with isNan is a value like this is also a NaN:
console.log("log line 5: ", !isNaN('0.0314E+2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read more about [html forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms):

```js
function KareAlan() {
 var kare1 = document.getElementById("kare1").value;
 var kare1n = parseInt(kare1, 10)
 document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML =
   "Result:" + " " + kare1
}
```

```html
<label for="kare1">Input Number</label><br>
<input type="number" value="5" id="kare1" oninput="KareAlan()"></input>
<h3 id="sonuc"></h3>
```